# gsdll.init_with_args parameters for Win32 display device

Tags: ghostscript

I intent to use gsdll32 to display postscript in a Win32 window (not ghostview).

I need help with the parameters needed by gsdll_init_with_args.

The function immediately returns error -0x12 or -0x100.

I tried several parameter combinations in various sequences:

```
-sDisplayFormat=16#030804
-dDisplayHandle="1234"
-dDisplayResolution=96
-sDEVICE=display
postscriptfile.ps
```

As a second question:
What should the parameters be if I want to pipe in the postscript data programmatically ?

Examples would be nice.

Seppe

Answer (score 0):

The supplied source code for Windows uses gs_dll_init_with_args(). If you look in /ghostpdl/psi/dwmain.c, function new_main(int argc, char *argv) then at about line 328 you can see the call happening.

You can follow this through in a debugger to see what the arguments look like (they get sanitised before arriving here). Get it to work the way you want on the command line, then break here with those arguments and you can see what your own code should be providing.

To send the data buffer-by-buffer, we don't have an example. However, you start by calling gsapi_run_string_begin(), then repeatedly calling gsapi_run_string_continue() until you exhaust the data, then call gsapi_run_string_end(). Obviously you will have to check the return code to see if an error occurred.

Finally; please check the AGPL to be sure you can conform to the license restrictions.